# Get Current URL of iFrame

Tags: javascript, url, iframe, dns, postmessage

I have tried to do an alert message in the onload event of the iframe with the code
"this.contentWindow.location.href"
but due to Javascript's same origin policy, I get the alert message of 'undefined'.  I am trying to use window.postmessage to work around this obstacle with the goal of knowing the current URL of the iframe onload.  Any step in the right direction with or without postmessage will be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: try var x=document.getElementById("myframe");
var w=(x.contentWindow || x.contentDocument)

Answer (score 1):

If the page loaded inside the iframe is hosted on a different domain it is not possible to get its href. The only thing you can get is the original src attribute of the iframe.